# Problems with integration tests after upgrading H2 database from 1.4.200 to 2.0.204

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, h2

Recently I have upgraded `H2` database in our `SpringBoot 2.5.8` project from version `1.4.200` to `2.0.204`. It is used for testing purposes only. For production we use `PostgreSQL 12.9`.
It seems that after upgrading some words become keywords in `H2` database for example: `day`, `value`. After invoking integration test `Hibernate` fails on `DDL` part.

- [Postgres 12 - Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html#KEYWORDS-TABLE)
- [H2 - Keywords](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords)

What is the best solution for that case?

1. Review all entities and apply back-ticks around reserved column names:

```
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "day", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate day;
```

```
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`day`", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate day;
```

2. Provide dedicated `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` and override `toPhysicalColumnName` method only for integration test purpose. Check list of reserved keywords in `H2` database and quote them.

```
# Datasource related properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=[project-related-package-name-here].strategy.CustomH2NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

I think first solution should work both with `PostgreSQL` and `H2` databases. Although `day` identifier is non-reserved in `PostgreSQL 12.9` it might be in the future releases.
Second one should sort out the problem with `H2` database.

What do you think about that? Maybe there are better solutions for that case? Or maybe take a list of reserved keywords from `SQL:​2016` standard and apply them to both databases via custom `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`?

Comment: Option 3, use test-containers and use PostgreSQL for testing. There are more breaking changes in that H2 release, is there a specific reason you upgraded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In H2 2.0 you can use [SET NON_KEYWORDS](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_non_keywords) setting by appending `;NON_KEYWORDS=DAY,VALUE` to JDBC URL, but the normal solution is to quote all identifiers in generated SQL unconditionally with `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`, for example.

You also should normally have `;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH` in JDBC URL of H2 when you try to use it instead of PostgreSQL. But it's a bad idea to use different DBMS for production and testing **<s>and Hibernate ORM doesn't fully support H2 2.0 yet</s>. Edited: Hibernate ORM 5.6.5.Final has basic support of H2 2.*.* and some additional issues were fixed in newer versions.**