# Getting SQL error after H2 upgrade from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, h2

Upgraded H2 from 1.4.200 to 2.0.206 and now in my integration tests I'm getting a 42001 Syntax error in SQL statement (`JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException`) around this select: `attributes0_.value[*] as value3_8_1_`

I'm using hibernate entities. Also, using H2 only in a test environment.

I tried:

- setting the `H2Dialect` in the test `yaml` file
- logging the SQL statements to see if there's anything suspicious, with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I had an entity (hibernate) field name equal to a reserved word: `value`; that's why the stacktrace pointed it out with an asterix (`[*]`). A full list of keywords/reserved words [can be found here](https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords).

[This answer solved my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70601906/1774643), and I'm reposting here for the sake of people searching "h2 upgrade sql error"

Since it's a test environment, I made the quick fix of setting `globally_quoted_identifiers: true` in my test YAML file.

For production environments, make sure you either:

- [set the globally quoted identifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.2/reference/htmlsingle/#data.sql.jpa-and-spring-data.creating-and-dropping), like I did
- [set h2 non keywords](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_non_keywords)
- [read up on h2's compatibility feature](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility)

or a combination of these.

Comment: setting NON_KEYWORDS seems to handle some scenarios but I do have another case where hibernate generates H2 restricted keywords like LIMIT when we have derived queries like findTopByEmployee() which compiles to something like select e.* from employee e where e.dept = ? limit ?

Anyone faced this and found a fix?